# Google Sheets YouTube API Published Date Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I have a google sheet setup for pulling YouTube API information like duration, title, etc. However I'm struggling to get the function working for the video date.

does anyone have any advice?

```
function getYoutubeDate(videoId){
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=" + videoId;
  url = url + key;
  var videoListResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = JSON.parse(videoListResponse.getContentText());
  return json["items"][0]["snippet"]["publishedAt"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `snippet` part in your request:

Change:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=" + videoId;
```

To:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id=" + videoId;
```